# Router Link com variáveis

Tags: angular, rotas

novamente venho trazendo uma dúvida sobre Angular!!

Sou desenvolvedor angular a 1,5 anos e até hoje não encontrei uma maneira de utilizar RouterLink passando a URL através de uma variável.

As maneiras que eu tentei foram todas essas:

```
<a [routerLink]="{{item.url}}">{{item.label}}</a>
<a [routerLink]="[{{item.url}}]">{{item.label}}</a>
<a [routerLink]="[/{{item.url}}]">{{item.label}}</a>
<a [routerLink]="getUrl()">{{item.label}}</a>
```

Porém todas essas não funcionou... rs

Alguém poderia me dizer se existe uma maneira de realizar isso?

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 0):

Aprendi pessoal....

Primeiramente e mais importante, você deve obrigatoriamente, importar o modulo do angular: 'RouterModule', sei que é básico, porém é bom deixar 100% claro.

Depois disso você deve passar sua variável sem {{variavel}}, da seguinte maneira:

```
<a [routerLink]="item.url">{{item.label}}</a>
```

Essa variável, deve ser do tipo 'string'.

Answer (score -3):

Tenta isso.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]">
```